# Update recyclerview when update SQLite in PhonecallReceiver

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-recyclerview, phone-call

In my project I want to update realtime my recyclerView when I get an incoming call and update my SQLite database. How can I accomplish that ?

With my code as it is I have to reopen the main activity in order to refresh the recyclerView.

If you need extra code please ask

**MainActivity:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        {
        
            private ArrayList<PhoneNumber> contacts;
            private RecyclerView recyclerView;
            private RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter;
            private DBHandler dbHandler;

            IntentFilter intentFilter;
            CallReceiver callReceiver;
        
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
                dbHandler = new DBHandler(MainActivity.this);
                contacts = new ArrayList<>();
                intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
                callReceiver = new CallReceiver();
        
                
                contacts = dbHandler.getAllContacts();
        
                rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(contacts, this);
        
                recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        
                recyclerView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
        
        
        
                intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
                intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
                registerReceiver(callReceiver,intentFilter);
            }
        }
```

**CallReceiver:**

```
public class CallReceiver extends PhonecallReceiver{


@Override
protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {

    notifyAboutTheIncomingNumber(number, ctx);

}

@Override
protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
}

@Override
protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
}

@Override
protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
}

@Override
protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date missed) {
}


private void notifyAboutTheIncomingNumber(String number, Context context)
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            ExtractRating exRating = new ExtractExtractRating();
            Notification not = new Notification();
            DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(context);

            String rating = exRating.getPhoneNumberRating(number);

            not.showNotification(number,rating,context);

            dbHandler.addPhoneNumber(number, rating);



        }
    }).start();
}


}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter:**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

// variable for our array list and context
private ArrayList<PhoneNumber> courseModalArrayList;
private Context context;


// constructor
public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<PhoneNumber> courseModalArrayList, Context context)
{
    this.courseModalArrayList = courseModalArrayList;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    // on below line we are inflating our layout
    // file for our recycler view items.
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.phone_number_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    // on below line we are setting data
    // to our views of recycler view item.
    PhoneNumber model = courseModalArrayList.get(position);

    
    holder.phoneNumberTextView.setText(model.getPhoneNumber());
    holder.phoneRatingTextView.setText(model.getRating());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    // returning the size of our array list
    return courseModalArrayList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{

    // creating variables for our text views.
    private TextView phoneNumberTextView, phoneRatingTextView;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        // initializing our text views
        // TODO: 3/17/2021 rename
        phoneNumberTextView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.idPhoneNumber);
        phoneRatingTextView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.idRating);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: when a receiver is called add the contact to the database and then youradpterName.notifiydatasetchanged()  for recyclerview load the updated data.

Comment: Second Choice using MVVM to update the live data to observe.